# Converting TimelineLite to gsap.timeline()

Tags: reactjs, transition, gsap

I'm new to gsap and loving what it can do. I was following a tutorial for page transitions and I have run into errors with TimelineLite. I understand in version 3 it's recommended to use gsap.timeline instead. Are you able to help me update the following code?

```js
import Highway from "@dogstudio/highway";

import { TimelineLite } from "gsap";

class Fade extends Highway.Transition {
  in({ from, to, done }) {
    const tl = new TimelineLite();

    tl.fromTo(to, 0, 5, { left: "-100%", top: "50%" }, { left: "0%" }).fromTo(
      to,

      0.5,

      { height: "2vh" },

      {
        height: "90vh",

        top: "10%",

        onComplete: function () {
          done();
        },
      }
    );
  }

  out({ from, done }) {
    done();
  }
}

export default Fade;
```

here is the link to all the code:

https://github.com/TomFawcett/EduMemory

The only two files that should be involved in the animation is transition1 in the src/components and index.js.

I am trying to get the animation to happen to all the pages (except for "Home") when I click the buttons in the home page and is redirected to the other pages.

Comment: The [GSAP 3 Migration guide](https://greensock.com/3-migration/) can help you convert the old syntax to the new. As for specifics applied to your code, we [already helped on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/26737-help-converting-timelinelite-to-gsaptimeline/).